# SMD Code Parts BE P04 & AE P04

Tags: components, surface-mount, plc

I'm looking to find out what these parts are on a PLC controller.

Both are SOT-89 packages.

The AE P04 I suspect maybe something to do with a constant current circuit for +24vDC for a 4-20mA loop sensor therefore I think this could be a LDO regulator.

The BE P04 appears to be part of a 0-10vDC output.  Is this likely to be another LDO regulator used for constant current?

Comment: Maybe pO4? Seems like an [NPN transistor](http://www.datasheetarchive.com/dl/Scans-064/DSA2IH00146583.pdf)

Comment: Fairly sure its not unless its a dual package of some sort.  SOT-89 has four pins.  The output circuit is buffered using NPN transistors however I have two small SOT23 devices that I assumed were this buffer.

Answer (score 1):

Given the component layout I was incorrect in assuming the two small SOT23 devices were NPN transistors.

A bit of further investigation using [s-manuals site](http://www.s-manuals.com/smd/be)leads me to believe that BE P04 is a BCX55TA and is indeed part of the output buffer with a BCX19.  The other small SOT23 device was a BAV70.